# How to set default language as 'en' in case language version is not created in sitecore

Tags: redirect, sitecore

In my sitecore website, there is a tricky requirement in redirects.
There are external redirects which are moving from sharepoint to sitecore item to some external redirect.
For ex : /abc.aspx (sharepoint_URL) to /abc (sitecore item) to http://abc.ly (external URL).

In /abc (sitecore item) we have only english version of item whereas http://abc.ly  can have many language version. If website is cookied in english than its working properly, in other languages its showing 404 error page which is genuine because of version count is 0 over there.

Requirement is if there is not other language version of item than it should point to 'en' version i.e global. 
Restriction is that versioning of item in sitecore is not acceptable to marketers, and i dont want to use fallback module right now. What i tried is :

```
Language currentLang = Sitecore.Context.Language;
                    Language LangEn= Language.Parse("en");
                    if(currentLang !=LangEn)
                    { currentLang =LangEn;
                    }
                    Item versionItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Context.Item.ID, currentLang);


                    if (versionItem.Versions.Count == 0){ // do something }`
```

Kindly suggest ASAP

Comment: Why don't you simply make the fields on the redirect item "Shared", then they will be returned for any language version.

Comment: All the fields of related redirect templates are already checked in "Shared".
But still failing for me.
Whenever (versionItem.Versions.Count == 0) and count is 0 its sends to 404 response page.

Comment: Have you published your items and templates?

Comment: yes, checked all publishing target, indexes and everything, they are working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look into language fallback. There is a [module on the marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/modules/language_fallback.aspx) to help you do this.

That being said, given the field is shared it will take far less time to just log into Sitecore and create a version in each language.

If this is going to be happening often, you could create a command template which will run code to create the item in all languages. That might save your authors some time.

Comment: But he's specifically requesting the "en" version of the item, which is all that the fallback module would do anyway. Its strange the item is null/no version since he's saying that the item is created in that language.

Answer (score 0):

I got a very precise solution over here [http://www.roundedcube.com/Blog/2010/tackling-fallback-fields-and-values-in-sitecore] where I just needed to add a processor in config and made a class accordingly. It did work for me.

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" />
<processor type="YourAssemblyHere.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FallbackLanguageProcessor, YourAssemblyHere " />
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LayoutResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

And add the corresponding class to your project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace YourAssemblyHere.Pipelines.HttpRequest
{
public class FallbackLanguageProcessor
{
public void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
{
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item contextItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
if (contextItem == null || contextItem.Versions.Count > 0)
return;


Sitecore.Globalization.Language language = Sitecore.Context.Language;
if (Sitecore.Context.Language.Name != "en")
language = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("en");
Sitecore.Data.Database contextDatabase = Sitecore.Context.Database;
Sitecore.Context.Item = contextDatabase.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID, language);
}
}
}
```

Thanks for suggestion and more ideas are most welcome.